# Get title attribute from string with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

```
string asd = "<area href='#' title='name' shape='poly' coords='38,23,242'/>"
```

how extract text from title atribute in c#

and then insert another atribute after title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search : `(?<=title=')[^']+`

replace: `something`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/nR3vQ8

something like this in your case:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
    string input = "<area href='#' title='name' shape='poly' coords='38,23,242'/>";

    // Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
    // ... The pattern N.t indicates three letters, N, any character, and t.
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=title=')[^']+", "something");

    // Write the output.
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

**update**

for taking out the title attribute as match use this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // First we see the input string.
    string input = "<area href='#' title='name' shape='poly' coords='38,23,242'/>";

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"title='(\w+)'",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
    }
}
```

output

```
name
```

Comment: I need replace the text after get title value, how get value of  title,. thanks in advance

Comment: @Alex which value are you talking about ? can you give an example

Comment: I need value from title attribute,.. in my example the value is 'name'

Comment: then dont replace it, just keep it in a capture group, wait i will update my answer

Comment: i just gave you a code sample, you can build upon the regex

Comment: I solve like this string matchString = Regex.Match(item, "<area.+?title=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In particular you may be interested in the HTMLAgilityPack answer.

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<a[^>]*?title=\"([^\"]*?\"[^>]*?>");
```

A couple of gotchas:

This will match is case-sensitive, you may want to adjust that

This expects the title attribute both exists and is quoted
        Of course, if the title attribute doesn't exist, you probably don't want the match anyway?

To Extract, use the groups collection:

```
reg.Match("<a href=\"#\" title=\"Hello\">Howdy</a>").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: parses "<a[^>] *? title =" ([^ "] *?" [^>] *?> "- No paired closing brackets).